# How to optimize: having COUNT(*)>1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, index-tuning, materialized-view, query-performance

Without considering the indexes,
Is there a way to re-write this query and get the same result quicker?

```
select fo.OrderNo, fo.OrderItemSeqNo, COUNT(*)
from Facts.FactBackOrder fo
group by fo.OrderNo, fo.OrderItemSeqNo
having COUNT(*)>1
```

When I re-write it as the the followig, it even gets worse.

```
;WITH R1 AS (

select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fo.OrderNo, fo.OrderItemSeqNo ORDER BY fo.OrderNo, fo.OrderItemSeqNo) AS N
       ,fo.OrderNo
       , fo.OrderItemSeqNo
from Facts.FactBackOrder fo
)

SELECT * FROM R1 WHERE N = 2
```

OR THIS:

```
;WITH R1 AS (

select COUNT_BIG(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fo.OrderNo, fo.OrderItemSeqNo) AS N
       ,fo.OrderNo
       , fo.OrderItemSeqNo
from Facts.FactBackOrder fo
)

SELECT * FROM R1 WHERE N > 1
```

It is a fact table in a datawarehouse. 
the indexes are on the picture below.

[image]

An Indexed view in this situation would use much less space than an index.
I have this situation in a similar indexed view -- you can see the code below:

```
CREATE view [dbo].[VProcessStatus]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
select processstatus, 
      StatusCount = COUNT_BIG(*) 
      FROM DBO.tbltaxtransaction
      GROUP BY processstatus
GO

GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[VProcessStatus] TO [mydomain\itdevelopment] AS [dbo]
GO


CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_VProcessStatus] ON [dbo].[VProcessStatus]
(
    [processstatus] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [pscheme_ProcessStatus]([processstatus])
GO
```

when I look for the space used by this view and the underlying table:

```
sp_spaceused 'tbltaxtransaction'
go
sp_spaceused 'VProcessStatus'
go
```

I get the following result:

[image]

The only extra is that this indexed view is partitioned according to the PARTITION schema and PARTITION functions below:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [pscheme_ProcessStatus] AS PARTITION [pfunc_ProcessStatus] TO ([FG01], [FG02], [FG03], [FG04], [FG05])
GO

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pfunc_ProcessStatus](int) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 2, 3, 9)
GO
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64670/discussion-on-question-by-marcello-miorelli-how-to-optimize-having-count1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now moved from dev to production.
the table FactBackOrder has 4,183,289 rows.

We're in sql server 2012.
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3412.0 (X64) 
    Mar  2 2014 01:25:09 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

But I don't want to use Columnstore indexes - these tables are updated very often.
Maybe in sql 2014?

the original query plan of the query I wanted to improve the performance of is:

[image]

the only way I found out to improve the orginal query was to add an index to the table.

```
create index idx_FactBackOrder_OrderNo_OrderItemSeqNo 
on Facts.FactBackOrder (OrderNo,OrderItemSeqNo) with (online=on)
```

When I then run the query, I notice it takes longer than the original without index.
the new query plan, after creating the index is as follows:

[image]

I immediately drop the newly created index:

```
drop index idx_FactBackOrder_OrderNo_OrderItemSeqNo on Facts.FactBackOrder
```

I then create an indexed view:

```
--drop view [dbo].[VfactBackOder]

CREATE view [dbo].[VfactBackOder]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
select fo.OrderNo, 
       fo.OrderItemSeqNo, 
       COUNT_BIG(*) as the_number
from Facts.FactBackOrder fo
group by fo.OrderNo, fo.OrderItemSeqNo
GO
```

create the clustered index for the indexed view:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_VfactBackOder] ON [dbo].[VfactBackOder]
(
    OrderNo, OrderItemSeqNo
)
go
```

The when I run the query using the newly created indexed view instead of the original query referencing the underlying tables:

```
select fo.OrderNo, 
       fo.OrderItemSeqNo,
       fo.the_number
from VfactBackOder fo
where fo.the_number > 1
```

I get a non satisfactory result. 
then I add another index to the view:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[VfactBackOder] ([the_number])
INCLUDE ([OrderNo],[OrderItemSeqNo])
go
```

Now the query flies like a rocket.
the new query plan is:
[image]

And looking at the space used by the indexed view and the underlying table:

sp_spaceused 'Facts.FactBackOrder'
go
sp_spaceused 'VfactBackOder'
go

[image]

query is performing well enough, customers happy here.
thanks for all the comments.

Comment: You're causing quite a bit of confusion. (1) Your question is tagged SQL Server 2005, but your answer says 2012. Which is it? (2) Have you measured the space used on the *index* used to satisfy the query in the base table? Seems you are relying on sp_spaceused (which sums the space used for *all* indexes) and using that to determine that the indexed view is better.

Comment: I changed the tag to Sql Server 2012, it started on Sql Server 2005 but later moved up.